# Passing ListBoxItem's IsSelected property a UserControl inside the DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I have a List of UserControl elements in a WP8 application page.

I'm trying to enable the UserControl itself to have different visual effect when it is in a selected state in the list.

I have created a DependencyProperty (IsHighlighted) in the UserControl, and I am now stuck trying to pass the ListBoxItem's IsSelected property into the UserControl.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <userControls:MyControl IsHighlighted="{Binding Path=IsSelected ???}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

It could have been easy if the following was enabled in WP8:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}
```

But it's not enabled..

Tried many variations, and I am out of ideas. Anyone?

**EDIT:**

The following error appears on the console:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'IsSelected' property not found on 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter' 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter' (HashCode=6915811). BindingExpression: Path='IsSelected' DataItem='System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter' (HashCode=6915811); target element is 'WP8.UserControls.MyViewControl' (Name='userControlObj'); target property is 'IsHighlighted' (type 'System.Boolean')
```

Comment: Have you tried `IsHighlighted="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}"`?

Comment: `TemplateBinding` produces XAML exception. I have also tried the full version of `TemplateBinding`: `{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}` which seems to affect nothing.

Comment: what you wrote should work , have you tried putting a callback for the IsHighlighted changed in the dp definition and placing a break point there?

Comment: Indeed, the breaking point is not hit. See my edit...

Answer (score 0):

Super old thread, but in case someone else comes looking like I did.....

I had joy with:
"{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}

Comment: A joy? For us mortals, could you elaborate on your answer?